# bind своими руками

Tags: javascript

Я пытаюсь сделать свой `bind`, у меня получилось сделать так, чтобы результат был таким же(вроде как), но сама функция, которая возвращается, выглядит не так, как у метода `.bind`. Как мне добиться такого, как у метода `.bind`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу, чтобы первый и второй вывод в консоли совпадали, и чтобы при клике в консоли на мой вывод функции, меня перекидывало на функцию f1 в редакторе браузера, как это у оригинального `.bind`

```js
const Misha = {
  color: 'red',
  size: 'big'
};

function f1(a, b, c) {
  console.log('f1 ' + this.color + ' ' + this.size + a + b + ' ' + c);
}

Function.prototype.bindMy = function(context, ...args1) {
  const then = this;
  return function(...args2) {
    then.call(context, ...args1, ...args2);
  }
};

const bindMy = f1.bindMy(Misha, 1);
const bindJS = f1.bind(Misha, 1);
console.log(bindMy);
console.log(bindJS);
bindMy(2);
bindJS(2);
```

Comment: function () { [native code] } у меня .bind вот так выглядит, вы так же хотите, чтобы ваша функция выглядела?))

Comment: @Leonid обновил вопрос

Comment: Здесь на сайте выводит как я выше описал (yandex). В вашем варианте тупо повторяется исходная функция. В чем прикол? Просто преобразования для девелопа по-разному делает консоль. Суть то не меняется. Наверняка можно для консоли правила отображения менять, типа toString() только зачем?

Comment: @Leonid я хочу разобраться в JavaScript, как делать такие ссылки на функции, мне интересно. toSting не будет ссылаться на функцию, а просто сделает текст

Comment: EcmaScript это язык, а отображение в консоли это IDE разные и браузеры. Связи прямой нет. Стоит ли подстраиваться под определенную реализацию? Консоль это не то, что происходит, это - то, что посчитали нужным вывести для разработчиков разработчики соответствующих инструментов. Я думаю...

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, вывод консоли не специфицирован, каждый браузер сам решает что и как выводить. Нативный bind возвращает специальный объект, ты возвращаешь обычную функцию, поэтому требовать одинаковый вывод в консоль - не корректно

Comment: твоя реализация bind, кстати, неправильная, ты теряешь аргументы, который при вызове передаешь

Comment: @Grundy вроде же a и b передаётся

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, передай при вызове bind только a, а b передавай при вызове прибинженой функции и сравни результаты своей функции и нативной

Comment: @Grundy, вроде, теперь нормально работает

Comment: да, можно и так